# Remove default attributes from prestashop 1.6.1

Tags: prestashop, stock

I need help.

I need to know if there is any possibility of deactivating the default attributes of prestashop; And Do not add to the shopping cart. ?

The problem is the following,

I have a number of products created in prestashop, (2770) each product with color combinations. (9 different colors each product) and each product depends on a color and quantity (stock) to buy.

The problem comes when I use another module, to create all other combinations (m2 x m2) etc.

With this new module, I manage everything. Prices, quantities, colors, sales by meters etc.

But with this module, I have to eliminate the combinations (attributes) created in prestashop and create them directly from the new module.

But, I can not eliminate that they are in prestashop, because they are created by a dropshipping provider and they manage the stock every day by color attribute.

I have hidden the attributes created by the prestashop. (They can not be seen on the products page). So far so good.

I create the attributes in the new module.

But the problem comes, when adding a product to buy, to the shopping cart; My client selects the attributes and combinations of color created by the new module, but when adding to the cart two colors are added (the one that comes by default in prestashop) and the one of the new module.

I can not eliminate the combinations created by the dropshipping provider because I can not stop using the stock.

But I need the other module to create another series of combinations (sale by meters boxes) that prestashop does not do.

Question? I can in some way disable the prestashop default combination and not add it to the shopping cart.

Thanks for your help, forgive English (I'm using google translator)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to modify the update of your Dropshipping to arrive in your module (at least at the stock level).

Or make a script that once the vendor stocks the products in the shop, make a transfer of quantities in the other declinations, and then remove that from PS.

We are used to this kind of case, being a dropshipping specialist.

Regards,

**forgive English (I'm using google translator)*